# How can I watch the 17th (or last, if less) line in files of a folder?

Tags: bash, head, watch

I'm currently using

```
watch head -n 17 *
```

which works, but also shows all lines up to the 17th. Basically, I would like to only show the last line for each file that is shown with my current approach. How can I achieve that?

## Example

For the sake of example, let's reduce the line nr. to 7. So:

Example file:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

this line:

```
watch head -n 7 *
```

outputs

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

where I want:

```
7
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With GNU `awk`:

```
watch -x gawk '
  FNR == 17 {nextfile}
  ENDFILE   {if (FNR) printf "%15s[%02d] %s\n", FILENAME, FNR, $0}' ./*
```

Which gives an output like:

```
        ./file1[17] line17
  ./short-file2[05] line 5 is the last
```

Note that the `./*` glob is expanded only once at the time `watch` is invoked.

Your `watch head -n 17 *` was an arbitrary command injection vulnerability as the expansion of that `*` was actually interpreted as shell code by the shell that `watch` invokes to interpret the concatenation of its arguments with spaces.

If there was a file called `$(reboot)` in the current directory, it would reboot.

With `-x`, we're telling `watch` to skip the shell and execute the command directly. Alternatively, you could do:

```
watch 'exec gawk '\''
  FNR == 17 {nextfile}
  ENDFILE   {if (FNR) printf "%15s[%02d] %s\n", FILENAME, FNR, $0}'\'' ./*'
```

For `watch` to run a shell which would expand that `./*` glob at each iteration. `watch foo bar` is in effect the same as `watch -x sh -c 'foo bar'`. When using `watch -x`, you can specify which shell you want and for instance pick a more powerful one like `zsh` that can do recursive globbing and restrict to regular files:

```
watch -x zsh -c 'awk '\''...'\'' ./**/*(.)'
```

Without `gawk`, you could still do something like:

```
watch '
  for file in ./*; do
    [ -s "$file" ] || continue
    printf "%s: " "$file"
    head -n 17 < "$file" | tail -n 1
  done'
```

Giving an ouput like:

```
./file1: line17
./short-file2: line 5 is the last
```

But that would be a lot less efficient as it implies running several commands per file.

Comment: Thanks for the security note. Actually you're right and my command also didn't do what I needed it to do, i.e. watch added files, which your version also solves. The only downside is that I need to learn AWK, I had though this would be done with `find . -exec` or sth like this :D

Answer (score 11):

Combine `head` and `tail` like in these two examples:

```
$ seq 1 80 | head -n 17 | tail -n 1
17

$ seq 1 10 | head -n 17 | tail -n 1
10
```

So to solve your actual problem, command is:

```
watch 'for f in *; do head -n 17 -- "$f" 2>/dev/null | tail -n 1 ; done'
```

Note about the `2>/dev/null` part, it is needed because * will match directories and any files you might not have permission to read, which will produce error message, which you probably want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

another approach with find,exec and sed

```
watch find . -type f -name \"*\" -exec sh -c \'\( printf '%-50s ' {} \; sed -n 17p {}\)\' \\\;
```

Comment: Doesn't work for files with fewer than 17 lines.  Read the question carefully.